# Why keyerror occurs every time i use json library?

Tags: python, json, bitcoin

```
 `import requests
  def price():
    response=requests.get(url+coin)
    res_json=response.json()
    return float(res_json[0]['price_usd'])
 url='https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/'
 coin="bitcoin"
 price()`
```

> ### --------------------------------------------------------------------------- KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
>
> last)  in 
>         6 url='https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/'
>         7 coin="bitcoin"
>   ----> 8 price()
>
> in price()
>         3     response=requests.get(url+coin)
>         4     res_json=response.json()
>   ----> 5     return float(res_json[0]['price_usd'])
>         6 url='https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/'
>         7 coin="bitcoin"
>
> KeyError: 0

Comment: If you print out `res_json`, you will find it is a `dict`, not an `array`, and does not have the key `0`.

Comment: how to access the price key than

Comment: A JSON structure consists of nested lists and dictionaries.  Lists are indexed by number, dicts by name/key.

Answer (score 0):

Because that v1 API on coinmarketcap.com is now deprecated, down, and returns `{'statusCode': 404, 'error': 'Not Found', 'message': 'Not Found'}` on each and every request.

Comment: Show us the details of what you've tried. Show thr URL you load, the content you get from that URL, and finally the code you try to parse it with.

Answer (score -1):

This API is depreciated as Stated above, run the following code and the returning dictionary states the same thing.

```
{'statusCode': 410, 'error': 'Gone', 'message': 'WARNING: This API is now offline. Please switch to the new CoinMarketCap API. (https://pro.coinmarketcap.com/migrate/)'}
```

```
import requests
import json
TICKER_API_URL = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/'
def get_latest_crypto_price(crypto):

  response = requests.get(TICKER_API_URL+crypto)
  response_json = response.json()

  return response_json
price = get_latest_crypto_price('bitcoin')

print(price)
```